# Is there a way to "get" javascript objects using a function in the same way getElementById() is able to get html element objects?

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById('coolid').innerHTML = "pretty cool";
```

The code above will, to my knowledge, access an html element object by id named 'coodid" and that object, being an element object, has a property of "innerHTML" which allows me to replace that HTML nodes text with the text "pretty cool".

I also know getElementsByName() and getElementsByClass(), etc...these all allow me to access DOM elements (which to my knowledge are objects).  Ok, that's great.  But is there some way to access objects I create as well?  Like this:

var person = {
    name : "John",
}

```
object.reallyCoolImaginaryGetMyObjectFunction('person').name = "Tom";
```

I know this might seem quite strange and perhaps even pointless, but just out of curiosity I've been wondering about this. Does anyone have any idea?  Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like your getting JavaScript and the DOM (Document Object Model) mixed up.  with any javascript object you can access its properties directly.  in your example person["name"] will return you the value of that object.

Answer (score 2):

You can if they're stored on an object, and there's one special case (globals) which are automatically stored on `window`.

You do it using bracketed notation and a string, e.g.:

```
var obj = {
    foo: "bar"
};
console.log(obj["foo"]); // "bar"
```

Or of course if it's a global variable:

```
console.log(window["foo"]); // "bar"
```

...since global variables are properties of the global object, and we can refer to the global object on browsers as `window`.

Details: JavaScript has two ways to access properties: Dot notation with literal names (`obj.foo`), and bracketed notation with strings (`obj["foo"]`). In the latter case, the string can be the result of any expression, e.g.:

```
// These all do the same thing, in the end
console.log(obj["foo"]);
console.log(obj["f" + "o" + "o"]);
var x = "foo";
console.log(obj[x]); // x contains the string
```

Comment: functions declared like `function a(){ return {c: true}; }` are stored in the window object. So I can access properties and objects within them like `window.a().c //true`. How extensive is this ability? Can I search all JavaScript elements to find a particular property or method? Thanks!

Comment: @thomas About functions stored in the window object it is not true if you declare it within another function's scope.

Comment: @thomas: *"functions declared like function a(){ return {c: true}; } are stored in the window object."* Only if they're at global scope, and I always recommend **not** creating globals when you can avoid it (you almost always can). *"So I can access properties and objects within them like window.a().c //true. How extensive is this...?"* The `window.a` part is dead cheap, but calling a function that creates an object just so you can grab one of its properties and discard the object is wasteful. Just have `a` return `c` directly (`function a () { return true; }` and then `window.a() // true`.

Comment: Yeah, totally. I just made the object to return within the function because that was the original question, getting Javascript objects. `function b(){ return true;}` and `var b = function(){ return true;};` are both accessible with `window.b()`. How do you store functions so they are not in the global scope? You mean just like wrapping them in an onload function?

Comment: @aduch If I return a function within another `function a(){ return function b(){ return "inner"} }` `window.a()() //inner`. Isn't there a way to get at a named function within another?

Comment: @thomas: If you have a function declared *inside* another function, the inner function is not accessible from outside the outer function unless the outer function does something to *make* it accessible. So for instance: `function a(arg) {  function b(arg) { return arg * 2; } return b(arg); }` Since `a` does absolutely nothing to make `b` accessible, it isn't; it's private to `a`. In your example aove, `a` does something to make `b` accessible: It returns it. And so in that case, you could use the return value of `a()` to access it.